# How can I extract the WHERE Clause from a string that contains SQL?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

...or any clause in my case.

I'm trying to create a mirgration script for a project I'm currently working on, and in order to do that I need to parse a group of SQL scripts, extract the SELECT, FROM, WHERE, whatever blocks out of it and do the necesary changes.

Is there a library that does that sort of thing? If not, could someone please point me to the right direction?

The application is in PHP, using CodeIgniter 2.1.0 and the DB is in MSSQL 2008

Answer (score 2):

There's an older library for PEAR that should do exactly what you want: http://pear.php.net/package/SQL_Parser/.

Alternatively, you could just use regular expressions which wouldn't be as robust.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this because I can't seem to install the package in the server I currently work on...

I'm giving this class a try and will see how that goes http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/wiki/ParserManual

Comment: Good luck. SQL doesn't have all that complex of a grammar so you should be able to figure something out fairly easily.